# Connect two old pulse-dialing phones

Tags: diy, telephone

At work we have some old pulse-dialing (rotary) phones. We want to connect two of them to make a simple intercom. Whatever the number is composed (even one single digit) the other should ring and of course we need to speak/hear the voice.

How should I connect them? I read the Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse_dialing) but it does not say much about how to use them.

There is a similar question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/699736/intercom-from-old-corded-telephones), but I don't understand why he needs an external buzzer: don't phones already have this built in?

Comment: The POTS (plain-old-telephone-system) was deviously clever. What you're asking for isn't as simple as you might think.

Comment: @Transistor don't scare the people away, the task is rather simple

Answer (score 2):

For basic communication, a power supply, somewhere between 24 and 48 VDC, with 600 Ω series resistor, polarity unimportant, will power the phones. As soon as *both* are off-hook, they'll draw a few mA from the supply and one can talk and listen. Note that off hook, the voltage across each phone should drop to ~12 VDC: I.E., 24 V dropped across two phones, and ~24 V across the 600 Ω resistor.

To make the phone *ring*, 100 VAC, 20 Hz (other frequencies may be used for party lines, to selectively ring one phone) is inserted in series with the ~48 VDC, and the AC should switch off when the phone is off-hook (low impedance).

See ["State of the Art Networking"](https://www.ad-net.com.tw/everything-need-know-pots-plain-ordinary-telephone-service-analogue-phone-systems-master-101-class/) for POTS basics.

Answer (score 2):

You can buy something called a ring down generator to do exactly what you want.  Pick up either phone, and the device sends ring voltage to the other.  Pick up the other phone, and the device switches to bias current for communication.

https://vikingelectronics.com/products/dle-200b/

https://www.graybar.com/two-way-phone-line-simulator-32vdc-talk-battery/p/95017169?pcode=95017169

https://vikingelectronics.com/find-a-distributor/

Comment: Does the DLE-200B also provide the power for the phones? I mean, I have to just power the DLE-200B, connect both phones to its port and I'm done?

Comment: Ok, I found the answer. The only downside is that it is very expensive... I guess they don't think it's worth it, unfortunately.

Comment: Correct, the 200B handles everything.  I have one, and opened it.  There's a buncha parts in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect two Plain Old Telephone Service (POTS) phones together using just wires and a battery, and they can communicate.

However, ringing in POTS phones is achieved by sending high voltage pulses from the central office to the phone. One POTS phone usually can't cause another POTS phone to ring directly. It either requires circuitry in between the two phones, or a source of high voltage at the calling phone. Back when the dinosaurs roamed the earth, phones had a hand crank which was connected to a small generator which could generate that ring. That same mechanism was used in portable military phones at least through World War II.

So, if you want to ring a POTS phone, you need a source of high voltage, and a mechanism to control it (even if that mechanism is just a hand crank and a generator).

Also note that the button that is depressed when one hangs up the phone causes the same electrical effect as the rotary switch. You could actually dial a number without the rotary switch by drumming your thumbs on the hang up buttons. (It was quite easy to call the operator by this method, but it is quite difficult to dial a long number without making a mistake.) So, the circuit that decides to send a ring pulses to the other phone needs to distinguish between a "real" hang up, and a dialing pulse.